# Android: create dynamic frequency (sin) graph

Tags: android, graph, frequency, trigonometry

how can i create a dynamic frequency graph in android?
like this: http://www.jazzitalia.net/lezioni/sax/immagini/grafico1.gif without axes.
i have the phase, the amplitude, the normal data that is needed for a graph like this.
I've found this example: http://androidplot.com/wiki/A_Dynamic_XYPlot but i don't know if it's the perfect way to do this thinks...

Comment: Hi Zak Do you listen about AchartEngine.jar it will also help you to make graph Dynamically even i am also using it to show heart beat getting on run time and draw a line chart/bar/pie-chart/ etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamic plot example is a very good starting point for what you want. Change GetY and the Runnable to make it do the data the way you want it.

As for the style of the graph you can switch thhe fill off and the points off by passing in null to the apripriate parrameter on the LineAndPointFormatter.

Here is code to show how to switch various visual features off if you don't want them.  It's checked in with the source as TimedXyPlotExample but has not made it into a release yet.

```
    if (!mBackgroundOn) {
        // remove the background stuff.
        mDynamicPlot.setBackgroundPaint(null);
        mDynamicPlot.getGraphWidget().setBackgroundPaint(null);
        mDynamicPlot.getGraphWidget().setGridBackgroundPaint(null);
    }

    if (!mKeyOn)
        mDynamicPlot.getLayoutManager()
                .remove(mDynamicPlot.getLegendWidget());
    if (!mDomainLabelOn)
        mDynamicPlot.getLayoutManager().remove(
                mDynamicPlot.getDomainLabelWidget());
    if (!mDomainAxisOn) {
        mDynamicPlot.getGraphWidget().setDomainLabelPaint(null);
        mDynamicPlot.getGraphWidget().setDomainOriginLabelPaint(null);
    }
    if (!mBoarderOn)
        mDynamicPlot.setDrawBorderEnabled(false);
    if (!mRangeLabelOn)
        mDynamicPlot.getLayoutManager().remove(
                mDynamicPlot.getRangeLabelWidget());
    if (!mRangeAxisOn) {
        mDynamicPlot.getGraphWidget().setRangeLabelPaint(null);
        mDynamicPlot.getGraphWidget().setRangeOriginLabelPaint(null);
    }
    if (!mGridOn) {
        mDynamicPlot.getGraphWidget().setGridLinePaint(null);
        mDynamicPlot.getGraphWidget().setDomainOriginLinePaint(null);
        mDynamicPlot.getGraphWidget().setRangeOriginLinePaint(null);
    }
    if (!mTitleOn) 
        mDynamicPlot.getLayoutManager().remove(mDynamicPlot.getTitleWidget());
```

Comment: the achart seems good...
i try with this two answers, if someone have a simple example to show, well... thanks!